# Link to a personal resource in multiple answers if it is relevant/helpful?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, self-promotion

I was answering questions on SO today and I realized I frequently link to one of my own projects, which I will not post here to avoid self-promotion. The fact is that the website is a collection of standalone JS methods that anyone can plug into their code and use to accomplish various tasks.

So my question is if it is considered a violation or self-promotion if I copy-paste code from that website on an answer, link back to it and cite the code explanation from said website in my answer.

If it wasn't a resource I was maintaining myself, I would not even stop and think about this, but I'm a bit worried as this might be flagged as (self-)promotion.

**P.S.:** If you need context, feel free to ask for the project website or name or check my recent answers to find it.

Comment: Hmm so if I'm understanding this correctly, are you finding yourself frequently linking to your work because it potentially answers a fairly large variety of questions without actively seeking out any particular kind of question?

Comment: Yep, my *work* as you put it contains a lot of JS methods that are useful in different scenarios, especially if composed properly, so I find myself frequently quoting and linking to it when answering JS questions, which is the tag I focus on primarily as it is the environment I am most familiar with.

Comment: I should've stuck to your use of the word resource ;) That sounds like a sticky situation to be in. Usually we speak to users about self-promotion when we find that they're answering a narrow subset of questions to promote their product, but your case is clearly different from those.

Comment: @BoltClock So, should I approach this differently in the future? The reality is I could just copy-paste the code and explain it, without linking if that could get me in trouble. The aim here is not to promote the resource, but rather help people learn a bit more about the code and possibly solve future problems with the rest of the snippets provided.

Comment: It might not be entirely the same, but here's some advice I wrote up a while ago about linking to open source projects you maintain: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229085/how-to-offer-personal-open-source-libraries/229091#229091

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think linking back is fine, as by doing so you are providing a reference for these snippets (even if it's to a resource that you maintain).

I think the best approach here is to ensure your answers are tailored to each question, even if they end up being based around the same code snippets. That way readers can learn how to apply the snippets to different types of problems and get the most out of them, in line with your goal.

Consider experimenting with original code in answers where appropriate. Every problem has multiple solutions, some more tailored to the individual problem than others in a way that ready-made snippets won't always be the most optimized for. This way you get to diversify your answers even further, so you don't feel like you're always providing the same solutions to various questions.

If two questions are so similar that one could be answered by linking to the other with the same answer (which won't always be the case, of course, but can sometimes be), consider casting a duplicate vote on one instead.

Answer (score 8):

There's nothing wrong with the links if they are useful and relevant to your answer. Depending on the triviality of the code snippets, you might not even need to cite the explanation - but make sure to include the snippet itself in the answer instead of just linking it.

However, it's still self-promotion. Our [guidelines for that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) require that you disclose your affiliation with the resource in the answer. So do not write

> These snippets from [that website - explained there](http://example.com) - will help you with…

but rather write

> These snippets from [**my** website - explained there](http://example.com) - will help you with…

and everything will be OK.

Comment: That's pretty good advice. I'll try to retroactively update all answers I can find to disclose my affiliation.

Comment: @AngelosChalaris [Not too many](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1650200+is%3Aanswer+url%3A"https%3A%2F%2F30secondsofcode.org%2F*"), it seems :-)

Comment: Thanks a ton for that link, btw as the project is not *mine* exactly, but I am part of the team, I will probably state in a parenthesis after the link that I am one of the maintainers, instead.